# Binding to {{}} with firebase simple login auth

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm using email/password for an app. When I register a user, they choose a username and it binds to a $rootScope variable called authUser.

I then use it in a divbar at the top that indicates that they're logged in as so:

```
<span>welcome {{authUser}}</span>
```

This works fine and their chosen username binds to it after they register, as I bind their username to the variable in a callback.

However, when I hard reload the page, it doesn't bind anymore. It seems like it takes a moment for the page to recognize that the user is logged in,
And by that time, angular has already run through its $apply cycle and the only thing I see on the navbar is "welcome".

Is there a way to know at what point (after a hard page reload) the logged in user is recognized? If possible, I'd like to chain some sort of callback or .then() function to bind or apply $rootScope.authUser then.

I guess this may be somewhat related to an asynchronous call, where the data must be used with a promise to guarantee success.

Any tips on this would be appreciated. Ill have access to my source code in about an hour if you need specific details but I think this problem may be more conceptual than about actual code implementation.

Thanks a bunch SO!

Comment: Have you tried calling scope.$apply in the callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get notified when the user logs in you can register an event listener like this:

```
$rootScope.$on("$firebaseSimpleLogin:login", function(e, user) {

});
```

If you just want to know whether the login state has been initialized then you can use `$getCurrentUser()`:

```
var auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(this.dbRef);
$scope.loginStateDetermined = false;

auth.$getCurrentUser().then(function (user) {
  $scope.loginStateDetermined = true;
});
```

Checkout the docs for more info:

[login-related-events](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/blob/gh-pages/documentation.md#login-related-events)

[$getCurrentUser()](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/blob/gh-pages/documentation.md#getcurrentuser)

Comment: Thanks, rob. The first code snippet you wrote worked perfectly!